# react native wont import another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a very simple react native application which is just two screen as of right now, an app.js and a login.js

While I was setting this app up, I wanted to display the login component inside the app component.

Here's how the app.js component looks like.

```
import React from 'react';
import {  View } from 'react-native';
import Login from "login.js"

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Login > </Login>
      {/* <Text>This is a test</Text> */}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here's how the login.js looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Input } from 'react-native';

const users = [
  {
    name: "Sarthak",
    age: 29,
    address: "BG3",
  }
]


export default Login = () => {
  return (
    <View>
    <View>
  <Text>{users[0].name}</Text>
      <Input></Input>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Text>Password</Text>
      <Input></Input>
    </View>
</View>
  )
}
```

The error I get is this 
`Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string( for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in`

I know it is a pretty common error but I am not able to find a solution to it. Could someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Import Statement is wrong

**Your Import**

`import Login from "login.js`

**Correct Way**

If they are in same folder, use this

`import Login from "./login.js"`

If they are in different folder, use this,

`import Login from "./../_dirname/login.js"`

Comment: OMG, I deleted the project coz it wasnt working and I couldn't figure out why, but thank you so much. This was plain negligence on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Fix this:

```js
export default const Login = () => {
```

Comment: I dont think constants can be exported as default. 

The app says so. Sorry, this didnt work.

Comment: Well, you're either importing your component using the wrong path or the thing I said above.  You can also try default exporting a function instead of arrow function, but if you remove `export default` your statement is not a valid JavaScript, so this is my best guess.

Comment: That's the thing. I am importing using intellisense, so I don't think it has an error in importing (I manually checked anyway). I am also using react snippets to generate component. And I'm taking care of when to use named exports vs default exports. Even if I put the entore component in the same page (thus, removing the need to import), It still is giving me the same error and I am on the verge of pulling my hair out. I am using expo, if that helps